# Data flow visualisation

Tags: data-visualization, dataflow

I'm searching for a program where I can visualize all my data flow. I've made a simple example:
[image]

Is there a way how I can visualize all the data. I've found examples of "Prefuse" and "Flare". But there's too much to add to the examples. Isn't there a nice program wich has it all?'

- it's preffered when I can connect the data to a database. So the whole process will be automated.
- it's preffered when I can collaps/uncollaps the systems and application flow(e.g. when I click on an application, the arrows appear).

I hope someone can help.

Comment: Maybe my example above is more to the BPM than data visualisation?

Answer (score 1):

you can use Graphviz (http://www.graphviz.org/) for creating the vizualization.
for the database connection, you could use a programming language to generate the input to the graphviz program.
I had this same problematic and used a combination of SAS and Graphviz to solve it.
hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks or the quick reply Aykin, I´ll take a look into it.

Comment: It seems Graphviz can only create an image of the data flow. But I can´t create an interactive flow with this software. Too bad...